# Error sending text message Android

Tags: android, sms

I am attempting to create a simple app that can send a text message from my android cell phone to another cell phone, but at the moment I am using the emulators. The problem I am getting is that the app keeps getting stopped unexpectedly.

I looked at my logCat and I notice I get this line

> 12-13 23:36:49.611: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29001): java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: User 10131 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

But this confuses me because in my AndroidManifest.xml I have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>   

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I did a single step as well and I crash at this line

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

with the arguments as follows

- phoneNumber: My Cell phone's number as a string in the format "XXXXXXXXXX"
- null: null
- message: "testing"
- sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);
- PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
          new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

With SENT being

> String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

and DELIVERED being

> String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

I have no idea what to do now. I have googled and I didn't see anyone else with my problem.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<uses-permission ...>` tags need to be under the `<manifest>` tag, not the `<application>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very very very much!! I have spent a lot of hours trying to figure out this problem. It doesn't help that every website I saw had the <uses-permission> tag under the <application> tag.

Comment: @Barda4 - It's always good to read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html). In this case, the section titled "CONTAINED IN" would have set you on the right path. :)