# Error in send message to one android emulator to another android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am new in Android.Currently i make the simple app which take message from one emulator and send it to another emulator.I can't receive the Message in second emulator.Here is my code.
MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_send);
    final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MessageSend);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sm.sendTextMessage(e1.getText().toString(), null, e2.getText().toString(), null, null);
        }
    });
}
```

2.ManifestFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vap.telephonysecond" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity>
            android:name=".smsSend"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sms_send" >
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

3.Log

```
        10-01 20:40:40.604  23793-23815/com.vap.telephonysecond E/Surface﹕             getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xac078100
        10-01 20:40:56.802  23793-23793/com.vap.telephonysecond E/AndroidRuntime﹕             FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.vap.telephonysecond, PID: 23793
        java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10058 does not have             android.permission.SEND_SMS.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber            (ISms.java:768)
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:310)
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:293)
        at com.vap.telephonysecond.smsSend$1.onClick(smsSend.java:27)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run            (ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am using 5556 or 5554 number for send SMS

Comment: Could you post your entire manifest code?

Comment: Yes here is a entire log file

Comment: Not the log, `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: No only posted the permission needed.

Comment: I know. But you might have put the permissions in the wrong place, please post the entire manifest

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` should go outside of the `<application>` tag. Keep it at the top level, inside `<manifest>` and `</manifest>`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vap.telephonysecond" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
    ...
```

If it still doesn't work, clean and rebuild your project. This solution is known to work. See: [Error sending text message Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499737/error-sending-text-message-android)